# Ionic 3 post request not working in android device

Tags: ionic3, angular5

When I send post request to webservice it works on browser but gives error on android mobile like **response with status: 0 for URL: null** 
Please help me to solve this issue.

My service.ts

```js
Login.ts
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
@Injectable()
export class RestProvider {
  constructor(public httpClient : HttpClient, public http: Http) {
     console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
 }
  
  getlogindetails(credentials) {
  let apiUrl = 'http://example.com/data/service.php?Method=';
  
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
        return this.http.post(apiUrl+'Login', JSON.stringify(credentials))
        .map((res: Response) => res.json());
      }
}
```

```js
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [
   
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpModule
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  
   providers: [
    RestProvider
  ]
  
  export class AppModule {}
```

Login.ts File

```
 import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public toastCtrl: ToastController, public restProvider: RestProvider, private http: HttpClient, public menu: MenuController) {

      }
      verifylogin() {
         this.restProvider.getlogindetails(this.loginData).subscribe((result)=>{
         console.log("result:"+result);
          }, (err) => {
          //this.loading.dismiss();
          alert("err:"+err);
          this.presentToast(err);
        });
      }
```

Above code is working on browser but not working on android device. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: First, try to check in network inspector while inspecting your app from chrome then let me know what is the exact error.

Comment: It's working in google chrome but not in android device

Comment: yes, I understand that it is working when you run your app in chrome but I am saying you just inspect your app through chrome. use this link https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/debugging-an-ionic-android-app-using-chrome-dev-tools-6e139b79e8d2. Then go to network inspect to check the response or error and let me know what error you are getting